# How does GeoMedia know what feature classes are in a database?

Tags: geomedia, intergraph

I've got a set of tables that have been migrated over from one GeoMedia database (Oracle) to another (Oracle); in different schema's of course.

I can't see the relevant Feature Classes when I look at the destination database (I can only see the pre-existing ones).

How does GeoMedia know which Feature Classes are available in the database? Can I just add the relevant Feature Classes to some fixed table name or is it more involved than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMedia's meta data is stored in GDOSYS.

Updating this manually is not a trivial task. Forunately, there is the  Database Utilities application (Start->Programs->GeoMedia Professional->Utilities->Database Utilities) just for these kinds of situations.